# Making custom properties queryable in partial EntityFramework class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, partial-classes

I've extended my auto generated EntityFramework classes with partial classes containing different properties.

Now this works just fine, except I can't use those properties in my LINQ queries because EntityFramework can't translate them to regular SQL.

I don't really know what I should call those kinds of properties, so searching around failed for me... How can I use those properties in an Entity Framework LINQ-Query?

```
public bool IsDeleted { get { return DeletedOn != null; } }
```